# Parsing DITA / XML files with text encapsulated nodes in php

Tags: php, xml, parsing, xml-parsing, dita

I'm trying to parse a `.dita` file, but there is a node inside another node, and while that isn't weird, there is actually text surrounding the inner node, it looks a bit like this:

```
<node>
    Hello this is a <xlink src="example.com">LINK</xlink> that you may click
</node>
```

I can get the text from `node` and i can get all instances of `xlink`, yet the text from the `node` will look like this:

```
Hello this is a  that you may click
```

As you can see, the word `LINK` is missing, and even though i can call the `xlink` node and get an array containing the word `LINK`, it hasn't thus far been possible to place the words back, as their position is unknown.

I'll have to add that checking for 2 spaces wouldn't work, as there can also be 2 spaces in the original text, and thus the position of the words won't be correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `DOMElement::$textContent` contains the text content of all descendant nodes.

If you fetch values via Xpath expression you can use the `string()` function to cast the first node into a string - returning its text content.

```
$xml = <<<'XML'
<node>
    Hello this is a <xlink src="example.com">LINK</xlink> that you may click
</node>
XML;

$document = new DOMDocument();
$document->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($document);

// access the text conent of the node element
var_dump($document->documentElement->textContent);

// use Xpath string() function
var_dump($xpath->evaluate('string(self::node)', $document->documentElement));
```

Output:

```
string(45) "
    Hello this is a LINK that you may click
"
string(45) "
    Hello this is a LINK that you may click
"
```

Comment: Awesome, this does it :)

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved by using regex operations modules to import :

- `import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET`
- `import re`

Add this python function to your code 
Pass reference of node to this function.

```
def getTextFromTagNode(node):
    textString = re.sub(r"(<.*?>)", '', ET.tostring(node).decode("utf-8"))
    return textString
```

`textString` returns the desired result.
The function removes all the tags and is left with texts.

If there are any `\n` in the strings, replace it with an empty string.
Hope this helps